# Import CSV File to MYSQL DB Automatically

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I would like to ask for your help please. Here's the scenario.

From my web application: I will upload a CSV file everyday from my everyday sales data.

Next on the server where my file was saved, it should be automatically inserted to MySQL DB.

I've done the insertion but manually, using command line in ubuntu.

What I want to achieve is that every time I upload a new CSV file on my webpage, it will be automatically inserted to my MySQL Database.

I've done this to do the insert to DB: but this is only for a specific file. what if there is new file uploaded with different name?

```
mysql -uname -ppassword --local_infile=1 DASHBOARD -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/www/html/webapp/files/files.csv' INTO TABLE files_temp  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 ROWS (column1. col2, col3, col4)"
```

Comment: Please avoid using ALL CAPS, especially in the title. It's considered yelling.

Comment: Can you add a hook on your upload procedure to do the insert?

Comment: Look at [LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) and if you can tap the upload of the file, then stream it over the mysql connection. Depends a bit of which mysql client libraries you are using.

Comment: MySQL have no built-in instruments which may scan the filesystem. So you must use some tool external for MySQL which will detect the fact of file transferring and then will initiate importing process (by starting either command-line client with proper importing query or any importing tool like mysqlimport).

Comment: Apology @tadman, i would like to say emphasize :) not yelling.

Comment: Emphasize your question by having a title that communicates the specific problem. Try and step back from the goal and describe the specific impediment you're having.

Comment: @tadman, added the procedure I use.

Comment: I'm actually new to this kind of thing on scripting specially in bash. Im struggling how can i automate this, everytime theres a new CSV file uploaded.

Comment: Do you want the insert to occur immediately after you upload the file, or can it happen at a fixed time of every day? You mention you have a website where you upload the file. So it probably makes sense to change the code of the website so that it triggers the LOAD command immediately. On the other hand, if you just want the upload to happen at a fixed time, then set a cron job to run the command.

Comment: Cant you make a bash file with this code and then schedule running this bash file using cron?

Comment: @ADyson, everyday i will upload a file cut off is 8pm. Maybe run every 8pm.

If so, how can i do this on CRON JOB? is the files names are different everyday? What is the script needed?

Comment: @Bogaso, I use the above code per file to insert CSV data to MySQL DB. It is a success, i inserted the code to bash script just make it executable. My concern is, how can i make a script that will read the latest uploaded file everyday and insert the data to mySQL db.

Comment: I would change the webserver code to always save it with the same name, that's probably the easiest thing, assuming you can edit that code. Either that or get bash to search for all csv files in that folder and then use a loop to load them all (even if, in reality, there's only ever one). And then delete them afterwards, or archive them, so they don't get loaded again the next day.

Comment: @ADyson, actually I cannot edit the code because this was built not using the native code. But via PHPRunner. Thats why my option is backend :(

Comment: ok well I think the bash script to search and manage the contents of that folder is your best option then.

Comment: Making a replacement file-upload option shouldn't be too hard. Handling file uploads in PHP isn't that complicated and would allow you to hook in and upload as CSV to the database. Alternatively you need to poll the directory and track which files you've already imported, it's actually a lot more work.